# python azure blob storage md5 check fails on blob upload using put_block_blob_from_path

Tags: python, azure, hash, md5, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to upload a blob to azure blob storage with python sdk.  I want to pass the MD5 hash for validation on the server side after upload.

Here's the code:

```
blob_service.put_block_blob_from_path(
        container_name='container_name',
        blob_name='upload_dir/'+object_name,
        file_path=object_name,
        content_md5=object_md5Hash
)
```

But I get this error:

```
AzureHttpError: The MD5 value specified in the request did not match with the MD5 value calculated by the server.
```

The file is ~200mb and the error throws instantly.  Does not upload the file.  So I suspect that it may be comparing the supplied hash with perhaps the hash of the first chunk or something.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is sort of an SDK bug in that we should throw a better error message rather than hitting the service, but validating the content of a large upload that has to be chunked simply doesn't work. x_ms_blob_content_md5 will store the md5 but the service will not validate it. That is something you could do on download though. content_md5 is validated by the server for the body of a particular request but since there's more than one with chunked blobs it will never work.

So, if the blob is small enough (below BLOB_MAX_DATA_SIZE) to be put in a single request, content_md5 will work fine. Otherwise I'd simply recommend using HTTPS and storing MD5 in x_ms_blob_content_md5 if you think you might want to download with HTTP and validate it on download. HTTPS already provides validation for things like bit flips on the wire so using it for upload/download will do a lot. If you can't upload/download with HTTPS for one reason or another you can consider chunking the blob yourself using the put block and put block list APIs.

FYI: In future versions we do intend to add automatic MD5 calculation for both single put and chunked operations in the library itself which will fully solve this. For the next version, we will add an improved error message if content_md5 is specified for a chunked download.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Why not make it so it will validate the whole blob after upload completes?  Doesn't seem sensible to include that parameter (content_md5) when you can't use it for blobs that have to be chunked.  Re https, can you point to any resources which show how to do this?  Thanks!

Comment: Https is on by default, but you can send it explicitly if you want when you setup the blob service using the 'protocol' parameter. The service doesn't have something to validate the full blob *after* upload if it was done in chunks. Content MD5 is used only on the current request body due to general HTTP protocol. So, the MD5 per chunk is the correct solution when it can be implemented by the lib (or if you want to implement it manually with put block).

Answer (score 0):

I reviewed the source code of the function `put_block_blob_from_path` of the Azure Blob Storage SDK. It explained the case in the function comment, please see the content below and refer to https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python/blob/master/azure/storage/blob/blobservice.py.

> **content_md5**:
>
> Optional. An MD5 hash of the blob content. This hash is used to
>      verify the integrity of the blob during transport. When this header
>      is specified, the storage service checks the hash that has arrived
>      with the one that was sent. If the two hashes do not match, the
>      operation will fail with error code 400 (Bad Request).

Answer (score 0):

I think there're two things going on here.

- **Bug in SDK** - I believe you have discovered a bug in the SDK. I looked at the source code for this function on Github and what I found is that when a large blob is uploaded in chunks, the SDK is first trying to create an empty block blob. With block blobs, this is not required. When it creates the empty block blob, it does not send any data. But you're setting content-md5 and the SDK compares the content-md5 you sent with the content-md5 of empty content and because they don't match, you get an error.

To fix the issue in the interim, please modify the source code in `blobservice.py` and comment out the following lines of code:

```
    self.put_blob(
        container_name,
        blob_name,
        None,
        'BlockBlob',
        content_encoding,
        content_language,
        content_md5,
        cache_control,
        x_ms_blob_content_type,
        x_ms_blob_content_encoding,
        x_ms_blob_content_language,
        x_ms_blob_content_md5,
        x_ms_blob_cache_control,
        x_ms_meta_name_values,
        x_ms_lease_id,
    )
```

I have created a new issue on Github for this: https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python/issues/99.

- **Incorrect Usage** - I noticed that you're passing the md5 hash of the file in `content_md5` parameter. This will not work for you. You should actually pass md5 hash in `x_ms_blob_content_md5` parameter. So your call should be:

> ```
> blob_service.put_block_blob_from_path(
>         container_name='container_name',
>         blob_name='upload_dir/'+object_name,
>         file_path=object_name,
>         x_ms_blob_content_md5=object_md5Hash
> )
> ```

Comment: It is a bug in that we should throw a better error message rather than hitting the service, but validating the content of a large upload that has to be chunked simply doesn't work. x_ms_blob_content_md5 will store the md5 but the service will not validate it. content_md5 validates the contents of a particular request but since there's more than one with chunked blobs it will never work.

Comment: @EmilyGerner-Microsoft - I think the bug is with trying to create an empty block blob first before doing chunked upload. This step IMHO is totally unnecessary and will create problem. For example, what if the chunked upload fails. In that case the user will have a zero byte blob sitting in their storage account. I agree with your comments about content_md5/x_ms_blob_content_md5.

Comment: Yeah, you're right -- this extra put is actually already removed in the next lib version. The one time that it's good is cutting short the upload if any access conditions don't match since otherwise those fail after upload on the put block list operation. Like I said though, removed. content_md5 would still be then applied to the put block list op though which still doesn't make sense, so for the next version we'll add an error message as well to cut that scenario off before the upload. Good catch!